# vsts-tasks Task fails

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Using VSTS online and my build no longer works because, I suspect, changes to the task task.logdetail which is within vsts-tasks. The error is

> Unable to process command '##vso[task.logdetail
>   id=151cf802-e696-4f5a-ad32-536d69a095b2;parentid=;name=DICOM
>   [Native]\x64..\libijg12\jmemmgr.c;type=Build;starttime=2016-11-28T20:08:43.0994807Z;state=InProgress;]'
>   successfully. Please reference documentaion
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
>
> Type is required for this new timeline record.

I have reported it to MS and await feedback, in the mean time does anyone know if it is possible to install a specific version of https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks at the time of building your project and thus avoid the problem.

Thanks,

Comment: How do you get that exception? Could you reproduce it? Which task throw this exception? What're steps of your build definition? Did you custom build task that execute ##vso[task.logdetail] command or using powershell step to run this command?

Comment: The issue can be reproduced by putting a [ in the directory name e.g /myproject [native]/

Comment: The workaround is that you can turn off Record Project Details.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce that issue too and I submitted a feedback [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3171). You can use **MSBuild task/step** to build your project.

Another workaround is that you could turn off Record Project Details.

[image]

**》if it is possible to install a specific version of https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks at the time of building your project and thus avoid the problem.**

There isn’t the way to install a specific version, you just can custom build task and upload to your VSTS, then use it.