# How do I add the 'Name' parameter to an 'Install MSI' task in Azure DevOps?

Tags: installation, deployment, tfs, windows-installer

I'm using an 'Install MSI' task to install an msi file as part of a deployment. The task is throwing the error:

> 2022-02-22T06:42:35.0716371Z ActionData: Updating component registration
> 2022-02-22T06:42:35.0839323Z ##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.logdetail id=5c578bc6-8e75-4147-992e-fe8cd643eaa2;parentid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;name=;type=release;order=1]Updating component registration' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
> 2022-02-22T06:42:35.0888633Z ##[error]Name is required for this new timeline record.

I'm using Azure DevOps on a local Team Foundation Server for the build and deploy process. From the error message I can see that the 'Name' parameter is missing. The deployment works fine when I'm installing to physical machines, but gives the above error when I'm installing to virtual machines.

There were apparently lots of people who had variants of this issue back in 2016, like [this guy on social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5b7afe3b-add9-48c8-b2e4-0caedce38d97/build-failing-because-of-missing-name) or [this guy on github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/2498) or [this guy on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853358/vsts-tasks-task-fails). Apparently in 2016 it was possible to turn off "Record project details", however this option is not available in newer versions of Azure Devops.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue in newer versions of Azure DevOps?

Versions: Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1, Agent 2.153.1, Install MSI 0.1.20.

Answer (score 0):

More a workaround than an answer, but I ended up switching the 'Install MSI' task to a regular 'Command line ' task.

Using the command line with the 'msiexec' command lets you install msi files just as easily as using the 'Install MSI' task.

Comment: I'd even argue that's a good practice -- relying on the command line when possible instead of platform-specific tasks/actions makes your pipelines more portable and will ease the pain of transitioning to GitHub Actions or other similar platforms in the future.